# Compare values in data frame and return results

Tags: r, compare, match

I have two data frames that I need to compare and generate an output of the comparison results. The dimensions are identical. Column and row orders match. I would like to compare each corresponding cell between the two data frames and determine whether they contain the same value or a different value. If the value is different, I need to know if both values belong to a particular vector I define or if they come from 2 different vectors. I've provided example code below.

I haven't been able to find anything in the forums that does exactly what I need, mainly because I need to know when the values are different, how different are they based on criteria I provide.

```
#Possible Value Types for the Data Frames
typeA = c("Green", "Blue", "Purple")
typeB = c("Red", "Orange", "Yellow")

#Create Data Frames to Compare
df1 = as.data.frame(cbind(rbind("Green","Red","Yellow"), 
            rbind("Green", "Purple", "Red"), 
            rbind("Orange", "Orange",NA), 
            rbind(NA,"Red","Purple")))

df2 = as.data.frame(cbind(rbind("Green","Red","Yellow"), 
                          rbind(NA, "Purple", "Yellow"), 
                          rbind("Blue", "Orange",NA), 
                          rbind("Blue","Red","Green")))

#Data frames compared must have identical dimensions
###INSERT FUNCTION HERE
myfunction = function(df1,df2){
  #compare corresponding cells and provide output based on match
  #example: compare cell df1[1,1] to df2[1,1]
  #if either df1[1,1] or df2[1,1] is NA then return NA, else...
    #if df1[1,1] matches df2[1,1] then return "Match"
    #if df1[1,1] does not match df2[1,1] but they are both in vector typeB then return "SAMEGROUP"
    #if df1[1,1] does not match df2[1,1] and one is in vector typeA and the other in typeB then return "DIFFGROUP"
}

###RUN FUNCTION
df.out = myfunction(df1,df2)

#expected output
#Match: The values in df1 and df2 for that cell are identical
#SAMEGROUP: The values in df1 and df2 for that cell are different, but
##they come from the same group (typeA or typeB)
#DIFFGROUP: The values in df1 and df2 for that cell are different, and
##they come from different groups (one from typeA, one from typeB)
#NA: One or both of the corresponding cells in df1 or df2 has an NA

df.out = as.data.frame(cbind(rbind("Match","Match","Match"), 
                          rbind(NA, "Match", "SAMEGROUP"), 
                          rbind("DIFFGROUP", "Match",NA), 
                          rbind(NA,"Match","SAMEGROUP")))
```

Thank you!

Comment: What does how different are they mean? It looks like you haven't given us any information regarding the criteria of difference that you're providing. I can give you a piece of code to identify whether a given table position is matched in a corresponding table but that's only have your question. This seems like two questions to me.

Comment: The values I have in my data frame can be grouped into categories. In my example case, typeA and typeB. You could think of it like having one group of even numbers and one group of odd numbers. Then pose the question, are the numbers the same? If not, are they both even numbers, both odd numbers, or is one even and one odd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to enforce your dimensionality condition:

```
stopifnot(all.equal(dim(df1), dim(df2)))
```

For the meat of your function: a naive, slow approach would be something like:

```
for(i in 1:dim(df1)[1])
  for(j in 1:dim(df1)[2])
    #complicated ifelse statement(s)
```

But this is easily vectorized. See:

```
a = matrix(1:9, 3)
b = matrix(c(1:8, -1),3)
ifelse(a == b, 'match', 'nomatch')
```

Your if/else would definitely more complicated, but I think you can figure out from there. It will be some assortment of nested ifelse() functions

Edit: Make a function that will return the group of a given value. Then, the statement

```
groupfun(a) == groupfun(b)
```

should just return a matrix of TRUES and FALSES, which will be easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you jarfa for the suggestion. That got me on the right track. This did the trick.

```
df1 = as.matrix(df1)
df2 = as.matrix(df2)

#ifelse(df1==df2, "match","diff") #test

ifelse(df1==df2, "Match", 
       ifelse(df1 %in% typeA & df2 %in% typeA,"SAMEGROUP",
              ifelse(df1 %in% typeB & df2 %in% typeB, "SAMEGROUP",
                     ifelse(df1 %in% typeA & df2 %in% typeB,"DIFFGROUP",
                            ifelse(df1 %in% typeB & df2 %in% typeA, "DIFFGROUP","TRYAGAIN")))))
```

Comment: Fast solution. I just finished a solution to this question that is 5 times slower (is also vectorized). edit: now 3x slower. lol